# Take a src img from a javascript object and put it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a program that picks an object from an array and displays a picture to a div.  How could I take a picture from an object and display it?  I was thinking something like this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var pizza = {
crust: bread,
topping: sauce,
imgURL: 'www.pizza.com'
} 

$('#mydiv').append(pizza.imgURL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#mydiv').append('<img src="' + pizza.imgURL + '"/>');
```

This appends an image in your #myDiv and sets it's image-source-url based on your pizza object

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Comment: I've updated my answer from your request.
Although the code is self explanatory, I realized it might be helpful to briefly discuss it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A solid solution would be to create the  element via jQuery, set its `src` to `pizza.imgURL`, and pass the element to the `append()` method. This ensures that the URL is properly escaped (it shouldn't be an issue, but it's certainly possible).

Here's [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtfx9spk/2/) to prove that this works. However, of course, the image doesn't load because, well, it's not a valid image URL.

```
var pizza = {
    crust: bread,
    topping: sauce,
    imgURL: 'www.pizza.com'
} 

$('#mydiv').append($('<img>').prop({
    src: imgURL,
    // don't forget your alt attribute!
    alt: 'pizza'
}));
```